# Adobe Flash & Createjs, getObjectsUnderPoint name 'return null'

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, easeljs

**EDIT:** http://snipsave.com/user/profile/smarty#12531 (index.html)
          http://snipsave.com/user/profile/smarty#12532 (the Javascript)

I am trying some stuff with Creates/Easeljs in Adobe Flash. But I'm stucked.

I try to do a drag and drop with the stage.getObjectsUnderPoint() Function, where I check if the names are matching and let it drop.

The problem is the following: I can't get the name of my movie clips (or instance name, not sure...). I have on my stage, to check them if they are the same as my ObjectsUnderPoint. But everytime I get "null".

My console is showing me only:

> [lib.eng]
>
> > 0: lib.eng
> >
> > > *"some properties until"*
> > >
> > > **name: null**
> > >
> > > parent lib.ins_eng
> > >
> > > > **name: "uk"**

So is there any way I can access that? I tried it with 2 shapes, where I have direct access to the name of the shape and...voila! I can do what I want to do. 
Can someone explain how this whole library thing works? Am I missing something?

If there are more questions or my explanation wasn't enough, let me know please.

Greetings

Comment: Yea, your current code would be helpful. And if your question is really to explain how "this whole library thing works", you're in wrong spot. Specific questions that have answers are what SO is for.

Comment: Ok, so i added my code in my original post. Forget about the library thing, i think it will be self explaining after we found the solution... ;)

Now its maybe clearer: I want to set the name for my library objects, so i can match them through ObjectsUnderPoint... :)  So far, Thanks Andy

Comment: The "name" property is not set on most items in the library automatically (Text instances seem to get a name property, but not MovieClips or Button instances).